# How to handle authorization event in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, authorization

I am trying to find a way to handle the authorization event for a page?

When i set the authorization for pages in the web config as shown below

```
 <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
```

I want to intercept the authorization event so i can write custom code to handle weather the user should be granted access.

Is there a handler in the global file to handle this, or is there a page event, or another way? I can't seem to find anything.

Thanks

Comment: I have given this question the wrong title, and don't know how to change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are doing, there is [AuthenticateRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.authenticaterequest.aspx) and [AuthorizeRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.authorizerequest.aspx) events that you can subscribe to in the global.asax or in your own [IHttpModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implementation.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to effect the outcome of the authorization event? I am calling a web service to check if they should be allowed access to a page but i still want to use the built in deny users authorization functionality so i know when to call the web service.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to add / set the context identity in the method